# Linear system solution with optimal parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I have a linear system where $x$ is unknown and $y$ is known, both vectors have proper dimensions such that:

$$A(\theta)x=y$$

matrix $A$ depends on a particular parameter $\theta$. I know that for a fixed $\theta_0$ i can solve the linear system by using projection methods (for example least squares which minimizes the euclidean norm). Now, I would like to find the optimal parameter $\theta$ that leads to $x$ with a minimum 2-norm. 
How can i proceed?
My idea was to derive the entire system with respect to $\theta$ and then solve the derivatives with respect to $\theta$ but other suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: $\min_{\theta} \| A(\theta) x - y \|_2^2$?

Comment: But this gives me the best parameter theta that solves the system. I want to find $\theta$ such as $||x||_2$ is minimized solving the system for such specific $\theta$